Azure Pipeline - Each - If
If tried to use a loop variable in an if statement but it does not work.
parameters:
  - name: env
    type: object
    default:
      Dev
      # - Test
      # - Prod
      # - PreProd
    
stages:
- stage:
  jobs:
  - ${{ each environment in parameters.env }}:
    - job:
      variables:
      - name: yamlPath
        value: "../infrastructure/azure_pipelines/vars/"
      - name: yamlFile
        ${{ if eq(${{environment}},'Dev')}}:
          value: "repository_vars_Nonproduction.yml"

Please help.

Hi Pshymonz, using double curly braces inside the if statement is not needed. If you have more question about the issue or my answer, please let me know.

You should change Dev to - Dev, and change ${{ if eq(${{environment}},'Dev')}}: to ${{ if eq(environment, 'Dev') }}:. You don’t need to use double curly braces inside the if statement.
The following yaml works.
parameters:
  - name: env
    type: object
    default:
      - Dev
      - Test
      # - Prod
      # - PreProd
    
stages:
- stage:
  jobs:
  - ${{ each environment in parameters.env }}:
    - job:
      displayName: ${{  environment  }}
      variables:
      - name: yamlPath
        value: "../infrastructure/azure_pipelines/vars/"
      - name: yamlFile
        ${{ if eq(environment, 'Dev') }}:
          value: "repository_vars_Nonproduction.yml"
        ${{ if eq(environment, 'Test') }}:
          value: "repository_vars_Test.yml"

      steps:
        - bash: |
              echo $(yamlPath)
              echo $(yamlFile)



